# Web application could not be started Capistrano Nginx Passanger DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, capistrano, passenger

I am trying to deploy my rails app to DigitalOcean. It is my first time to deploy rails app.

So I followed https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04 this tutorial. I did everything except the database.yml.example part since my repo is private. I use RVM for ruby.

When i go my IP address on my browser, I get this page   -> http://i.hizliresim.com/BvBYkp.png

I have been trying to solve this for 2 days and I am about to lose my mind because I can not find any solution.

Here is my **production.log** file.

```
D, [2017-01-29T07:34:02.835118 #16679] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(2623970102560787400);^[[0m
D, [2017-01-29T07:34:02.847575 #16679] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"^[[0m
D, [2017-01-29T07:34:02.867835 #16679] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.5ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2^[[0m  [["key", :environment], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-01-29T07:34:02.872345 #16679] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.1ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[35mBEGIN^[[0m
D, [2017-01-29T07:34:02.873998 #16679] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[35mCOMMIT^[[0m
D, [2017-01-29T07:34:02.874562 #16679] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2623970102560787400)^[[0m
```

If i forgot to add some logs, please tell me so I can add. Thanks

Comment: Are there no errors in the log, those are just debug statements?

Comment: So why do I get this page instead of mine? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I mean, there must be more in the log than those 6 lines, are there no errors in production.log?

Comment: If there aren't, then you need to look into the errors for nginx itself, probably somewhere in `/var/log/nginx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the solution.

In the `/etc/nginx/passenger.conf` I thought `passenger_ruby` part should be `/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby` Since I downloaded ruby there. **But this is totally wrong**. Original conf should be like this -> `/home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.3/ruby;`